# Enumerating every block/square in given area

Tags: qgis, google-maps

I have a list of 300 points of interests within 500m radius from a given point.

I need to automatically put numbers in every block/square and then list in which block/square each point of interest is located in. The attached image is just an example.

Is there a way to do that automatically without resorting to manual interventions (e.g drawing the numbers one by one).

[image: ex1]

[image: ex2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to obtain the blocks by using OSM roads shape files and the poligonize feature in QGIS and Model Builder.

The data of the roads were obtained from http://download.geofabrik.de/
Then I imported roads shape files into QGIS. I used the select features in QGIS and then the poligonize feature.

Answer (score 2):

One idea to think about:

- calculate the distance of each polygon centroid to the given point
- using a `row_number` function assign a value to a distance column in the polygon ordered by the distance to the given point

From there, it is just a matter of intersecting the points of interest to the polygons and grabbing the `row_number` value.